# OnBase & C# script

Tags: c#

I recently worked on a project to import Outlook Emails into OnBase Document Management System. Now I am in the process of enhancing this project.

When we receive an email, in the subject line, it contains numbers. I want to grab those numbers. So lets say if subject line contains:

> "My name is Hiren and my Driver license# 123456".

I want to pull that sub-string `123456` to populate a "Driver License" keyword box, in OnBase. The length of the numbers is 6.

How can I do that?

Comment: "*How can I do that*" - what exactly do you want to do? Get numbers from text string is one task and send it to OneBase is absolutely different task. So what exactly problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?  I've done a bit of scripting in OnBase (Unity API) but this is an old issue.

Answer (score 1):

This really has nothing to do with OnBase or any other integration.  You simply need to know how to extract a number from a string.  Where you store it is irrelevant. A simple way to do it would be using a regular expression:

```
var s = "My name is Hiren and my Driver license# 123456";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
foreach (var match in r.Matches(s))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways: Either using RegEx or Looking at the last 6 characters of the subject line if you can guarantee the structure.

Here is an example:
http://dotnetpad.com/lB2pmbs7

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mailBox importer, then is very easy, there is a keyword named "mail subject"  that store the subjet of the email. Then with VBScript you can get the numbers.
This could help you:
Create an action to create an expression, then type this VBScript:
right(%K00122;len(%K00122) - InStr(%K00122;"#"))
Replace the "%K00122" wiht the number that represents the key word tha have the subject.